# Disable notification ads in android app

Tags: android, admob

I use admob for ads in my app and its giving ads in the notification tray.

i use the following codes in my app for the add :

```
     adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad);
     adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
      <com.google.ads.AdView

     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"

    android:id="@+id/ad"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"

     ads:adUnitId="my id"
     ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
 />
```

How do i disable this annyoing notification ads from my app ?

Comment: I've got a better question: how can we disable ALL annoying notification ads? The world would be a much better place. Seriously though, good job for asking.

Comment: @wtsang02 You **clearly** misread my comment. [sic] "notification" ads.

Comment: @DannyBeckett Ah I did misread it.

Comment: I don't think the code you've shown is the source of your notification ads.

Comment: @Eric yes but i dont have any other code in my app but my friend says that he got notification ads in this tray with the star mark and my app name on that.  He even showed me the screenshot of that.

Comment: @ashwinbhy: Are you sure it was your app that created that notification ad? In my experience, Admob never had that feature. But do correct me if I am wrong on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admob didn't provide notification ads (luckily). 
So it's most likely that another app causes the notifications. If you have one of the newest android versions you can long click on the notification for app details. Other ways would be to look at running background services or install the app from the store which scanns all the apps on your device to find push ad sources.